# What is the purpose of Parameter "token" in "Register" method at MVVM Light framework

Tags: mvvm-light

public virtual void Register(object recipient, object token, Action action);

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems to be a way you can subdivide messages, so that messages with a certain token only arrive at the receivers which also use that token:

From http://blog.galasoft.ch/archive/2010/03/16/whatrsquos-new-in-mvvm-light-v3.aspx:

> Messages can now be sent through the
>   Messenger with a token.
>
> - To send a message with token, use the method overload
>     Send(TMessage message,
>     object token).
> - To receive a message with token, use the methods Register(object
>     recipient, object token,
>     Action action) or
>     Register(object recipient,
>     object token, bool
>     receiveDerivedMessagesToo,
>     Action action)
>
> The token can be a simple value (int,
>   string, etc…) or an instance of a
>   class. *The message is not delivered
>   to recipients who registered with a
>   different token, or with no token at
>   all.*